# django - applications in a project

Tags: django

I am little bit confused about the term application in a django project. I know that applications can be built that can be part of a project and the reason of this is to create reusable components (BTW it is brilliant idea).
I am building a web applications that will have 3 admin page (managing 3 different entities, eg. list/update/create/delete them). Also I will have a monitoring page and 1-2 other pages.

The question is that should I use 5-6 separate applications (3 + 1 + 1-2) or just one? Or create one for the administration and other one for the others? I don't want to use them outside this web application.

I began with the 5-6 separate applications but I have common stuff, like base structure (header on top, menu on left and footer at the bottom) of the web app, the jquery javascript file, etc. 
How would you split the django web app? Or shouldn't I worry about using more applications?
Not sure it is important but coming from the Java world.

Comment: I understand your question, but I highly recommend following the Django tutorial since it sounds like you are a new user. It will answer your current question, and I'm assuming a lot of your future questions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Hi jape, you are right, I have already found one answer to one of my question... thanks, V.

Comment: While I think that some people will advise to make an attempt to split functionality logically into coherent apps, my opinion is that if you try such a thing, you are likely to do it wrong (even if you are experienced). I believe that [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) and it's better to put everything in a single app (unless it's obvious it must be done otherwise). When you need it, you split it.

Comment: Hi Antonis, I have the same feeling. It sounds nice to create reusable components but as these stuff will be used only in my app so it's no point to separate them. One thing is for doing it as I am still learning Django so it can be a good learning lession to me how to work with applications. I just hope I won't regret it... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation it is not needed to create multiple apps. However, if the project grows it could make it more maintainable if things are separated. 
Many people start with everything in just one app.

Personally I prefer a 'base' app that only contains some layout things:  basic templates (header,footer - other templates extend from this), and also some general CSS, icons, and JS (jquery for example). This app can easily be re-used in other projects.

Comment: Thanks Ixer, it makes perfect sense!